# GN: Exporting Plant Growth Animation To Alembic Incorrect

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, alembic

I created this beautiful [Plant to Tree Growth Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6z1I4PS-nfA) at 30 fps using *Geometry Nodes* and just discovered that when i export the animation to [Alembic (.abc)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alembic_(computer_graphics)), the animation goes kaput. I have no experience with alembic. You can see the leaves all scattered with huge sizes and the stem growing branches ahead of time without any leaves.

[image]

Any idea what is going on? I think alembic supports geometry nodes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, only what exists as a mesh is exported to another format (i.e. also the *Alembic* format).

Therefore, you would have to convert all instances into a mesh using `Realize Instances` and then export it.

[image]

*However, this solution only works in Blender 3.2+!*

Comment: oh my! you saved my life! my client would have killed me XD Thank you sooo much!!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Well, I'm glad that you will stay with us here on BSE for a while and that you will continue to honor us with your interesting questions and answers :D

Comment: Yes! I definitely will. I'm having a lot of fun here! pretty much learned a lot while learning 3D stuff and blender for the past 5 months! and it's nice to have some awesome experts here like yourself :)

Comment: btw the export works but in the materials view all the leaves are transparent, i can only see the branches and trunk but when i select the tree i can see the orange outline around as if the leaves are invisible. but its fine in solid mode.

Comment: hmmmm i tested rendering, the leaves are invisible.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie When converting the instances into a mesh, the previously assigned UV mapping is lost. You would simply have to replace the node `Texture Coordinate` in the shader material "leaf" with the node `UV Map` and select the map "UVMap" there.

Comment: i tried plugging UVMap (with the leaf's UVMap object set) to Mapping node and tried all Type options, its still transparent. i can't get it to work :( can you send me the file???

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie https://blend-exchange.com/b/JoqKN1w5/

Comment: yeah that's what i did. leaves are still invisible in material mode. and don't render in eevee. but it does render in cycles. weird.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie OK, this is really strange. The file I just sent you works the same for me in Eevee and Cycles. In both cases the material is displayed correctly (Blender 3.2). ...could you please share your file?

Comment: it is!! it is a bug! it actually works in blender 3.2! i just checked. in blender 3.1 it doesn't XD no wonder the client didn't complain. he said it works for him so i guess he is on blender 3.2 as well. so it's a bug in blender 3.1. do u also have 3.1 and can confirm this?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Oh, yes, you are right: I can confirm the behavior in Blender 3.1 ...probably one of the many bugs. But main thing it went well for you anyway ;-)

Comment: yes thank you very much! :)